# How do I prevent and Android device from going idle in Ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

So I'm developing an Ionic application and I'm mostly targeting Android tablets.

How can I proceed to prevent the device from going idle when the app is launched? I want the screen to stay bright forever until the user possibly decides to close the app.

Comment: Have you googled "cordova keep screen on" ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a corova plugin for this.

There is a plugin that 'may' help:
https://github.com/Viras-/cordova-plugin-powermanagement

Also have a look at the Android Powermanagement API and eventually use the source code of the plugin as a starting point to make the required changes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html